# Pass constant value and variable (input) text from View to Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I'm fairly new to ASP.NET MVC and still getting used to some of the concepts.
I understand that to pass the value of a text box in the View back to the Controller, I can use Html.BeginForm and give the text box the same name as the corresponding parameter in the Controller Action.

Here's my situation: I have 2 buttons. I want them to call the same Action in the Controller. I want them to both pass the value for the text box (i.e. the "searchText").
However, I want one of the buttons to pass "false" for the parameter isQuickJump and I want the other button to pass "true" for the parameter isQuickJump.

Here is my View:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("SearchResults", "Search", FormMethod.Get))  {
<div id="logo" class="centered">
    <a href="SearchResults">
        <img alt="Search" src="../../Content/themes/base/images/Search.jpg" />
    </a>
</div>

<div id="searchBox" class="centered">
    @Html.TextBox("searchText", null, new { @class = "searchTextBox" })
</div>

<div id="buttons" class="centered">
    <input type="submit" id="searchButton" value="Search" class="inputBtn"  />
    @Html.ActionLink("Quick Jump", "SearchResults", "Search", new { isQuickJump = true }, new { @class = "btn" })
</div>
```

}

Controller:

```
public ActionResult SearchResults(string searchText, int? page, int? size, bool? isQuickJump, GridSortOptions sort)
    {
        var items = GetSearchGrid(searchText, page, size, sort);

        if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
            return PartialView("_SearchResultsGrid", items);

        return View(items);
    }
```

Any suggestions on how to do this?

I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use 2 submit buttons with the same name and different value:

```
<div id="buttons" class="centered">
    <button type="submit" name="isQuickJump" value="false">Search</button>
    <button type="submit" name="isQuickJump" value="true">Quick Jump</button>
</div>
```

Depending on which button is clicked the corresponding value will be sent to the server for the `isQuickJump` parameter. And since both are submit buttons, they will also submit all other input fields data to the server (which was not the case with the anchor that you used as the second button).

Comment: Glad I could help. If you don't have further questions and this answer helped you solve the problem you were having you might consider marking iot as answer by clicking on the tick next to it: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: Oddly enough, it was telling me "You can accept an answer in 5 minutes." Does it always make me wait a specified time before I can accept an answer?